# Mongoose find() with multiple criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find in my database (MongoDB) all the data records satisfying all the criteria that are defined (some might be undefined). I am using NodeJs as a server and mongoose to connect to the database.

For example, my database contains the following records:

Database Name: Movie

```
{title: 'A' , main_actor, 'A.A.'},
{title: 'B' , main_actor, 'B.B.'},
{title: 'C' , main_actor, 'A.A.'}.
```

If my request contains the following:

- title = 'A' and
- main_actor is undefined

and I do the following query:

```
Movie.find(title: title, main_actor: main_actor, .....)
```

the response is an empty array while I would like to get

```
{title: 'A' , main_actor, 'A.A.'}
```

What is the best way to find all the record either by 'movie' only, 'main_actor' only, 'movie' and 'main_actor'? In other word is there a way to ignore one or more fields if the searching criteria are undefined (I would like to avoid doing something like this:

```
if (criteria1 & !criteria2) { ...find(criteria1....)} 
if (!criteria1 & criteria2) { ...find(criteria2....)} 
if (criteria1 & criteria2) { ...find(criteria1,criteria2....)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$or` operator, if your value is undefined, the request will search for documents which has this field undefined.

Try with this :

```
Movie.find({
    $or: [
        {title: title},
        {main_actor: main_actor}
        // ...
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Now my problem is that if both criteria are defined it will also return records that do not satisfy both criteria. For example:


`Movie.find({
    $or: [
        {title: 'A'},
        {main_actor: 'A-A''}
    ]
});`

will return` [{title: 'A' , main_actor, 'A.A.'},
{title: 'C' , main_actor, 'A.A.'}.] ` while in this case I would like `{title: 'A' , main_actor, 'A.A.'} ` only

Comment: The $and operator should be used instead so, but if you have an undefined variable in your request, it will not returned what you want. For the $and, you must have the 2 value. I think you should change the way you received your data to avoid undefined main_actor

Comment: Yes, I end up creating an array with defined values only before passing it to the find() function.

Answer (score 2):

You must wrap criteria in object

```
Movie.find({title: title, main_actor: main_actor, .....})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find